# Dynamic TableLayout Android

Tags: android, dynamic, dynamic-programming, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am creating a android application where i have to show contents of sqlite in Android app.

So i decide to use TableLayout here.But the main point here is that columns and rows from sqlite database is not previously decided,so i need to create that type of layout that deal with dynamic columns and rows.

So here what i am doing is that i have created a layouts **sublayout.xml**, **cells.xml** ,**mainlayout.xml**.

**sublayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/subLayout_" >
</LinearLayout>
```

In this layout i am dynamically adding cells using **cells.xml**.

**cells.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cell_"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cell" 
    android:textSize="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And when my one row gets ready i simply added it to **mainlayout.xml**.

**mainlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/tableLayout_"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

But i am getting nullpointer exception here.

Here is my class code.

```
LinearLayout layout,subLayout_;

layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_);
subLayout_=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.subLayout_);

for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
Log.e("Column name", ""+columns[i]);
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cells, null);
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cell_);
tv.setText(columns[i]);
subLayout_.addView(v);
}

layout.addView(subLayout_);
```

Please help me what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, null);

    subLayout_ = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.subLayout_);


    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        Log.e("Column name", "" + columns[i]);
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cells, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell_);
        tv.setText(columns[i]);
        subLayout_.addView(v);
    }

    layout.addView(subLayout_);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach here.

Design your xml like this:

```
<TableLayout>
  <Tablerow>
    <Add your views here dynamically>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Create the textviews dynamically and go on adding it to the TableRow and finally add the TableRow to the TableLayout.